# Hosting a Honeypot to collect data

Tags: botnet, iot, honeypot, vps

I want to collect IoT botnets in order to analyze them. Are there any good VPS providers who allow to do that? - I'm a little cautious about this because of possible misconfigurations that could trigger a lifetime ban. I'm especially looking for european based providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most computers on the Internet are already being probed and attacked constantly, a honeypot is no different really.

So there is no particular problem hosting a honeypot since you are not initiating any attacks, you are just being a "victim" among so many others.

The one thing that will get you kicked out by the webhost, is to launch attacks from your VPS, or send spam which can cause their IP ranges to be blacklisted by Spamhaus and other actors.

In fact, you shouldn't be shy and could tell the webhost openly that you intend to host a honeypot for legitimate research purposes. Technically this is nothing special at all.

It is your responsibility to configure the server properly and make sure it won't be abused by attackers. For a start, you should review the firewall rules and you can proactively block ports you won't be using. If you are going to run a fake SSH server, then you can block the SMPTP, DNS ports etc. To run a VPS, it is assumed that you have sufficient sysadmin knowledge.

You could set up a lab at home on a virtual machine and test it, before going live.

Comment: One issue that is likely to come up with a hosted honeypot is that the security measures at the perimeter might need to be weakened to gain greater visibility at the honeypot. The hoster would need to be ok with that and facilitate that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hosting a honeypot is unlikely to be forbidden. What they won't like is to have the vps itself compromised (although some hosts wouldn't bat an eye, either). I would suggest you look at a provider you like, carefully read their ToS, then ask them explaining what you want to install and if it's ok. Most likely they will say yes.

They might want to request that you take an additional measure in your install (or offer to block themselves e.g. outgoing smtp from the vps), as well as taking a note in case they receive a false positive that your vps is vulnerable. Having explained your goal beforehand, makes very unlikely you would get such a ban (you will often be able to explain afterwards, too, but a prior communication can only help).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes, I already asked some providers and they said, that it's okey as long as I only use the VPS for legal activities.